# How to get a list of process ids of long command names, not command line parameters?

Tags: pgrep

Since there's a 15-character limit on the length of process names in pgrep, I've been using `pgrep -f` to give me a list of process id's of running commands with longer names. However, it includes the full command line parameters, and this gives wrong results.

For example: suppose `my_long_script_name.sh` is running while I `vi my_long_script_name.sh` (ignore editing a running program for the moment).

If I run `pgrep -f my_long_script_name.sh`, it returns the process id of both `my_long_script_name.sh` and `vi my_long_script_name.sh`.

How can I get a list of process id's (that I can feed to kill in a list, the same way `pgrep -d ' '` makes them) that are based only on process names not parameter lists?

I'm running Buster but see the same problem in earlier OS's such as Wheezy. As requested, if I run `sed -n l "/proc/$pid/comm"`, where `$pid` is `$BASHPID` of my terminal session, I get `bash$`. If I run `sed -n l "/proc/$pid/cmdline"`, I get `-bash\000$`. That's a lower case L, not a one, after `-n`. If I run `cat -vte`, it hangs.

Comment: Does `pgrep -l` do what you mean?

Comment: Similar: [how to write a pgrep pattern that (never) matches a zero byte?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/610982)

Answer (score 2):

The thing is there's no such thing as the *long process name*.

There's the *process name* (`/proc/pid/comm` on Linux) which on Linux is up to 15 bytes long, inherited from the parent and changed every time the process does a `execve()` system call to the first 15 bytes of the basename of the file being executed (but can also be changed to any arbitrary value with `prctl()` or by writing to that `comm` file).

That's what `ps` reports without `-f` or with `-o comm`. And what `pgrep` matches on by default.

And there's the *list of arguments* the process passed to the command it executed last (`/proc/pid/cmdline` on Linux). By convention, the first argument is the basename or a path to the file being executed.

`ps -f` or `ps -o args` prints the concatenation with space characters of those arguments, and `pgrep -f` matches on the resulting string. Because of that concatenation, you lose the information of where each argument starts and ends.

But if you can make the assumption that the first argument doesn't contain space characters, you can still match processes whose first argument contains `my_long_script_name.sh` with:

```
pgrep -f '^[^ ]*my_long_script_name\.sh'
```

(replace `pgrep` with `pkill` if you want to kill the corresponding processes).

For something more reliable, if on Linux, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
print -C1 /proc/<->(Ne[$'[[ ${"$(<$REPLY/cmdline)"%%\0*} = (*/|)my_long_script_name.sh ]]']:t)
```

That is, get the information directly from `/proc/pid/cmdline`, where arguments are separated by `$'\0'` and check that the part leading up to the first `$'\0'` is `my_long_script_name.sh` or ends in `/my_long_script_name.sh`.

Pipe to `xargs kill` if you want to kill the corresponding processes.

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice there is "15 bytes" limit to `pgrep` command before.

Comment: Thank you but it does not work for me. I suspect the problem is that there are characters preceeding $my_long_script_name.sh. When I do ps -Af | grep $my_long_script_name.sh, I see entries of the form: /bin/bash <space> path_to_the_script/$my_long_script_name.sh. I don't know why these other characters are present. How can I eliminate them -- possibly by invoking $my_long_script_name.sh differently -- or how can I do a pgrep or whatever that ignores them ?

Comment: @NewtownGuy, assuming you're on Linux, can you add the output of `sed -n l "/proc/$pid/comm"` and `sed -n l "/proc/$pid/cmdline"` (where `$pid` is the pid of the process of that bash shell interpreting your script) to your question?

Comment: I'm running Buster. I used $BASHPID for $pid when I ran the command from the command line. But I get this error message: sed: -e expression #1: character #1: missing command. Since it's -n, I followed it with a 'one'. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @NewtownGuy, that's a `l` (lowercase `L`), not `1` (digit one). Or use `cat -vte`, the idea being to clearly see what those files contain.