# Don't truncate the COMMAND column in ps

Tags: bash, shell, ps

I want to list process by their executable name, using the `comm` column. But it always gets truncated even when it's the last column:

```bash
$ ps -C systemd-tty-ask-password-agent -o %cpu,%mem,comm
%CPU %MEM COMMAND
 0.0  0.0 systemd-tty-ask
```

How do I make sure that the `COMMAND` doesn't get truncated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this is on Linux, the value that `ps` retrieves from the kernel is truncated to 16 bytes (including terminating zero byte), so there is no way for `ps` to show more information for that value specifically.

If you want to see more information about the command being run, you can look at the `args` column instead.

See [How to get a list of process ids of long command names, not command line parameters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/620823/86440) for details.